# Java - How to calculate CRC16 of BitSet

Tags: java, crc, crc16

I Have a Java BitSet where i have some data. The length of this BitSet is 545 bits.
Problem: All current known implementations can only work with a byte array, but converting my BitSet to a byte array will change the data because i need to do some padding.
Is there any known implementation which can handly my data without needing to adjust it to whole bytes?

Comment: What does "some padding" look like? What's wrong with getting the byte array and modifying it after the fact with your padding?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Standards_and_common_use), there are 22 conflicting definitions for CRC-16.

Comment: @StephenC "Conflicting" has an unnecessarily negative connotation. They are simply different 16-bit CRCs. (I count 30 different 16-bit CRC's in Greg Cook's catalog.)

Comment: I am merely using the word that the Wikipedia page uses.  Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: @JoachimSauer padding means i have to add zeros at the end of my data to fill the last byte. This will then change the checksum.

But i guess i will need to write it by myself..

Comment: @Phreag: that sounds like what [`BitSet.toByteArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#toByteArray()) already does. It can't really return "3/8th of a byte", so it set the unused bits of the last byte to 0 anyway. So unless your padding works differently in some way, I don't think there's anything you need to do.

Comment: Everyone has to pad. The question is whether you need a CRC on a flexible length BitSet (length to store), or 545 bits is fixed. 545 bits = 69 bytes = 35 shorts (16 bits). General for a BitSet one would probably use little endian (least significant byte first). So a `ByteBuffer.allocate(70).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putShort....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.toByteArray()` to get the bits into a sequence of bytes. You need to know what CRC-16 definition is required (polynomial, ordering, pre and post processing), and the order in which to process the bits. `.toByteArray()` will put the first bit in the set in the least-significant bit of the first byte.

Then you can use [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) to generate C code for the CRC-16 you need. The generated code includes a `crc16..._rem()` routine for updating the CRC with a number of bits. For a BitSet with `n` bits, you would first compute the CRC on the first `n >> 3` bytes. Then use `crc16..._rem()` to update the CRC using the `n & 7` bits in the last byte. It is straightforward to convert the C code to Java.